# Jquery AJAX Parsing displaying in the <select> dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a JSON object generated from my CodeIgniter

```
function getListLotJSON($projectId){
        $lotList = $this->reservationmodel->getListLot($projectId);
        if($lotList){
        $this->output
            ->set_content_type('application/json')
            ->set_output(json_encode($lotList));
        }
        else{
            //do nothing
        }
    }
```

This returns:

```
[{"LotId":"3","LotName":"1"},{"LotId":"4","LotName":"2"}]
```

Then in my AJAX:

```
$(function(){
$("#ProjectName").change(function(){

    var projectId = $("#ProjectName").val();
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:81/ORPS/reservation/getListLotJSON/' + projectId,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        error: function(result){
            alert('No Available Lot!');
        },
        success: function(response){
            $("#LotName").append($("<option>").val("").text("--Loading List of Lots Available--"));
            var lotDetails = response;
            console.log(lotDetails);

            $("#LotName > option").remove();
            $("LotName").append($("<option/>").val("").text("--Lot--"));

            $("#LotName > option").remove();
            $.each(lotDetails, function(){
                $("#LotName").append('<option value='+lotDetails['LotId']+'>'+lotDetails['LotName']+'</option>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

});

I wanted to append LotName as the text in the  and LotId as value. How do get the specific data to be displayed?

by the way, this is what console.log(lotDetails) gave:  [Object { LotId="3", LotName="1"}, Object { LotId="4", LotName="2"}]

It just displays UNDEFINED in the .

Please help. Thanks much!

Comment: Try this.LotId / this.LotName instead of lotDetails['LotId'] / lotDetails['LotName'] inside your $.each(lotDetails, function(){...});

Comment: is it possible to have to 2 ajax call in my change function? because I want to populate 2 <select>s from 2 different data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop is not correct:

```
$.each(lotDetails, function(key, value){
        $("#LotName").append('<option  value='+value.LotId+'>'+value.LotName+'</option>');
});
```

You are accessing your main lotDetails array. Which does not have a property LotName. You need the items inside. So you loop, and in the function you have 2 arguments, the key (index in this case) and the value. The object inside.

Answer (score 1):

In your each you are accessing the original array.

Try using something like this:

```
$.each(lotDetails, function(index, lotDetail){
                $("#LotName").append('<option value='+lotDetail['LotId']+'>'+lotDetail['LotName']+'</option>');
            });
```

I have passed the lotDetail argument to the each annonymus function. Now you can access each array element individually.

As you can see in the official jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

```
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```

The first arugmentis the index and the second is the value.

Hope this helped.
Let me know!

Cheers